# Serverless Framework - environment variables from file and manual

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have Serverless Framework function for AWS Lambda. I have secrets in AWS Secrets Manager (SSM) Parameter Store and other environment variables in local .yml files, for separate deployments (dev, stg, prod).

How can I use environment variables from both file and SSM?

Only secrets work:

```
functions:
  kinesisEvents:
    handler: kinesis_events_processing.lambda_handler
    name: kinesis-events-${self:provider.stage}
    package: {}
    maximumRetryAttempts: 2
    events:
      - stream:
          type: kinesis
          ... # omitted a few things
    environment:
      DB_PASSWORD: ${ssm:/${self:provider.stage}/db/db_password}
      API_KEY: ${ssm:/${self:provider.stage}/api/internal_api_key}
```

And only file also works:

```
functions:
  kinesisEvents:
    ... # as above
    environment:
      ${file(${self:provider.stage}.yml):}
```

But how can I combine those, so I have all those variables set as env vars in final deployment? I tried this, but it does not work and throws error during deploy:

```
functions:
  kinesisEvents:
    ... # as above
    environment:
      DB_PASSWORD: ${ssm:/${self:provider.stage}/db/db_password}
      API_KEY: ${ssm:/${self:provider.stage}/api/internal_api_key}
      ${file(${self:provider.stage}.yml):}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answers [here](https://forum.serverless.com/t/merging-environment-configs/5125/2), [here](https://blog.betomorrow.com/yaml-tips-and-tricks-for-concourse-ci-35a3b577a239) and [here](http://blogs.perl.org/users/tinita/2019/05/reusing-data-with-yaml-anchors-aliases-and-merge-keys.html). Basically, Serverless Framework has no particular support for this feature. However, it supports extended YAML syntax, which has anchor and dictionary merging capabilities.

So first I unpack the env vars from YAML config file, at the top of the file, and anchor it with `&env_vars` (like a variable for referencing, but in YAML):

```
env_vars: &env_vars
  ${file(${self:provider.stage}.yml):}

functions:
  ...
```

And then I use it, unpacking this dictionary:

```
    environment:
      <<: *env_vars
      DB_PASSWORD: ${ssm:/${self:provider.stage}/db/db_password}
      API_KEY: ${ssm:/${self:provider.stage}/api/internal_api_key}
```